# The element type 'bool' can't be assigned to the map value type 'Widget Function(BuildContext)'

Tags: flutter, routes

First of all, I'm new to Flutter, and I've been looking for a solution af an error I'm having when following a Udemy course.

This is all the code I have on my main.dart and I'm getting the error "The element type
'bool' can't be assigned to the map value type 'Widget Function(BuildContext)'."

I've seen this error on another people's code, but because I'm new and the code is not similar to mine, I cannot interpret the solution they get.

Thank you very. much for your help, I really appreciate it.
Flutter 2.2.3, Dart 2.13.4

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:componentes/src/pages/home_page.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
        debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
        title: 'Material App',
        initialRoute: '/',
        routes: <String, WidgetBuilder>{
          '/' : (BuildContext, context) ==> HomePage(),

        },

        );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Now that I saw your code, I realized I made a typo with double equal sign. That's why Flutter was inferring that the element has to be bool type.

I could not use the (context) => HomePage() because the BuildContext is needed in order to work (the program run, but I get a null value when taping). After removing one of the equal sign, the error was another. I think a I made another mistake, because after a while I re-typed the line of code '/': (BuildContext context) => HomePage() and it works.
But thanks, you helped me to realize my error.

Comment: Please add further details to expand on your answer, such as working code or documentation citations.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of **(BuildContext, context) ==> HomePage()**, use **(BuildContext, context) => HomePage(),**

**Edit 1:** My mistake, there is a second issue about this line.

Instead of **(BuildContext, context) => HomePage(),** use **(context) => HomePage(),**